# Python answering command prompts in terminal

Tags: python, command-line, terminal

I needed to some help on developing a piece of python software. Basically when it tries to do:

```
os.system("commandHere usernameHere")
```

I need it to answer the password prompt that comes up asking for the password. The password cannot be added in as the third argument unfortunately and I have no idea how to handle this. Also, another question, how do I receive the output from terminal into my python program?

Thank you! :)

Comment: Regarding reading output of a command, try this: [Subprocess Module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) you will most likely want subprocess.check_output()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're better using `subprocess.Popen` than `os.system`, as it allows you to send data to and read data from the process. Note that `Popen` takes a list of commands and arguments rather than a string with spaces, so `["commandHere", "usernameHere"]` rather than `"commandHere usernameHere"`. Once the `Popen` is complete, we can write into the process and read output from it as shown below.

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(["commandHere", "usernameHere"], shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p.stdin.write(b"yourPassword\n")   # What you need to input
result = p.stdout.read()           # The program's output
print(result)
```

Comment: I have used subprocess before but had no idea that this is the reason why people prefer subprocess versus os.system. Always learning something new everything, I'll test this out. Thanks! :)

Comment: Could you please outline what the "b" beside "yourPassword\n" is for? And what if we have multiple inputs? should it be another p.stdin.write?

Comment: The `b` changes the `str` (string) object to a `bytes` object - a collection of characters that can be easily pushed into a terminal, sort of like keystrokes. If you need multiple inputs, you can add another `p.stdin.write`.